# Is this charge controller datasheet schematic an idea circuit to use?

Tags: battery-charging, charger, texas-instruments

Background - Software Engineer with an interest in EE.

I'm looking to include a [bq2000](https://www.ti.com/product/BQ2000) battery charge controller in a circuit that I'm designing. I'm looking to use a bq2000 since it can use multiple types of battery chemistry, which is a requirement I'd like to include in my project (the bq2000 can make use of lithium-ion and Ni-based batteries). Upon looking at the [datasheet](https://www.digikey.com/en/htmldatasheets/production/22925/0/0/1/bq2000), it contains several examples of how to configure the temperature control and voltage divider, as well as other individual legs of the IC, but there was no example for how the MOD leg (Number 8) should be wired. To add to my confusion, the datasheet has this schematic, which shows a more detailed example circuit:
[image: figure 7 from the datasheet]

I have been under the impression that, like computer code, there are plenty of ways to create circuits, but you should use examples where possible. Is this an ideal schematic that I could (or should) copy-and-paste, and use as my own?

Or should I only be using parts of this example, and building a different schematic all together?

Comment: The datasheet schematics are usually how the part is designed to be used. If you don't have reason to deviate from them, don't.